# Complete IPv4 Address Space Output

Tags: python, ipv4

I am trying to run a .py file that will output a .txt file that contains all of the IP addresses from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255, but it is throwing an error in the Sublime Text Console. This is my .py file:

```
def ipRange(start_ip, end_ip):
   start = list(map(int, start_ip.split(".")))
   end = list(map(int, end_ip.split(".")))
   temp = start
   ip_range = []

   ip_range.append(start_ip)
   while temp != end:
      start[3] += 1
      for i in (3, 2, 1):
         if temp[i] == 256:
            temp[i] = 0
            temp[i-1] += 1
      ip_range.append(".".join(map(str, temp)))    

   return ip_range

output = []   
# sample usage 
ip_range = ipRange("0.0.0.0", "255.255.255.255")
for ip in ip_range:
    output.append(ip)
fo = open("output.txt", "rw+")
line = fo.writelines(output)
fo.close()
```

This is my console output:

```
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
]0;LeoLaneseltdKernel Information: 
Darwin 18.5.0 x86_64
```

Comment: While executing your code on terminal, there is no error at my end.

Comment: you don't have to use `rw+` I think `w+` should work. Which python version are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.7.10. @nikhilesh_koshti how are you running this from the terminal?

Comment: developer@Codys-MacBook-Pro-3 ~/d/.py> python ipv4.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ipv4.py", line 24, in <module>
    line = fo.writelines(output)
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Comment: This is my terminal output when I try to run it from the terminal ^

Comment: Incidentally, you can just do `from itertools import product; ip_range = ['.'.join(map(str, ip_address)) for ip_address in product(range(256), repeat=4)]` (that's a *lot* of addresses, though)

Comment: Do I run that as a .py file? For instance `python example.py`

Comment: Off: Consider the use of generators in this kind of functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified by some logging print to debug the flow of the code in the following way:-

```
   def ipRange(start_ip, end_ip):
       start = list(map(int, start_ip.split(".")))
       end = list(map(int, end_ip.split(".")))
       print('start', start)
       print('end', end)
       temp = start
       ip_range = []

       ip_range.append(start_ip)
       print('IP ADDRESS IS', ip_range)
       while temp != end:
          print('while ')
          start[3] += 1
          for i in (3, 2, 1):
             if temp[i] == 256:
                temp[i] = 0
                temp[i-1] += 1
      ip_range.append(".".join(map(str, temp)))    
      print('IP ADDRESS IS', ip_range)
      return ip_range


print("Executing the python script")
output = []   
# sample usage 
ip_range = ipRange("0.0.0.0", "0.0.0.10")
for ip in ip_range:
    print(ip)
    output.append(ip)
fo = open("output.txt", "w+")
line = fo.writelines(output)
fo.close()
```

Please find the following output(I have only print 10 ip addresses):-

```
[nikhilesh@pgadmin ~]$ python 2.py
starting the python
('start', [0, 0, 0, 0])
('end', [0, 0, 0, 10])
('IP ADDRESS IS', ['0.0.0.0'])
while 
while 
while 
while 
while 
while 
while 
while 
while 
while 
('IP ADDRESS IS', ['0.0.0.0', '0.0.0.1', '0.0.0.2', '0.0.0.3', '0.0.0.4', '0.0.0.5', '0.0.0.6', '0.0.0.7', '0.0.0.8', '0.0.0.9', '0.0.0.10'])
0.0.0.0
0.0.0.1
0.0.0.2
0.0.0.3
0.0.0.4
0.0.0.5
0.0.0.6
0.0.0.7
0.0.0.8
0.0.0.9
0.0.0.10
[nikhilesh@pgadmin ~]$ cat output.txt   

0.0.0.00.0.0.10.0.0.20.0.0.30.0.0.40.0.0.50.0.0.60.0.0.70.0.0.80.0.0.90.0.0.10
```

I am using python version 2.7.5

Comment: When I run that it throws this error:   File "iplookup.py", line 1
    def ipRange(start_ip, end_ip):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent